# Twig -Set variable as value

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this piece of code inside Twig loops that will render beautiful color to every first letter of key=>value

```
<i class="avatar avatar-color-95 avatar-letter-c">{{ firstletter(message.firstname)}}</i>
```

But I want this to display color in dynamic way, different colors depending the length of the value

```
{% for message in pagination %}
  {% set namecount = message.firstname | length %}
    {#{ dump(namecount)}#}//outputs number(length)
   <div class="container avatar">
     <i class="avatar avatar-color-12 avatar-letter-c">{{ firstletter(message.firstname)}}</i>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to do it like this

```
    <i class="avatar avatar-color-{{ namecount }} avatar-letter-{{firstletter(message.firstname)}}">
```

How do you do it? I tried to put qoutes between

```
"{{namecount}}"
```

and

```
"{{firstletter(message.firstname)}}
```

But it doesnt work. I cant find any docs for this in Twig docs,.How do you do it?

Comment: Yes {{ namecount }} should work. Did you check what is rendered in the class attribute?

Comment: You could just use `<i class="avatar avatar-color-{{ message.firstname|length }} avatar-letter-{{ message.firstname|slice(0, 2) }}">`. Unless you are going to be using the variable again there's not much point in setting a variable rather than using it inline.

Comment: @qooplmao could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the comments section...*

You could just use `<i class="avatar avatar-color-{{ message.firstname|length }} avatar-letter-{{ message.firstname|slice(0, 2) }}">`.

Unless you are going to be using the variable again there's not much point in setting a variable rather than calling the filter/function inline.